# CSS Word break when importing string from json not work

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am importing json file like that and pass it as prop to all componentts.

```
 const lang = require(`./languages/${language}.json`);
 setLanuageJson(lang);
```

Then use it particular component

```
 const t = props.languageJson;
<AccordionDetails style={{ padding: '0 0.5em' }}>
     <Typography className={classes.link}>{t['38']}</Typography>
</AccordionDetails>
```

Here is my css

```
link: {
color: '#A3A3A3',
lineBreak: 'anywhere',
padding: '0 5px',

...theme.typography.internbody,
// fontSize: '0.6em',
```

},

**Without lineBreak: 'anywhere' the whole content is coming in one line like that.**
[image]
**When using lineBreak: 'anywhere' some of the words are breaking**
[image]
Any solutions please

Comment: I think `overflow-wrap: break-word;` might work.

Comment: I already try that its not working

Comment: And it was better or worse or why you rolled back to `lineBreak: 'anywhere',
`?

Comment: as i mentioned without lineBreak: 'anywhere' text is not breaking as the text is coming from json file. normally text automatically break but it is not happening

Comment: Try again `overflow-wrap: break-word;` but with `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: with this it is working but same issue word is breaking as scenario 2 in question

Comment: Try adding `white-space: pre-wrap;` for the whole container.

Comment: Or also `word-break: keep-all;` Also please add all classes that you used and the classes that did not work to find good solution;

Comment: i have added all of this the only thing is working  lineBreak: 'anywhere',but it is breaking words. other properties are breaking design.

Comment: "Try adding white-space: pre-wrap; for the whole container" Did you tried?

Comment: yes i added that also

Comment: do you want to see the component?

Comment: Sorry I am do not know how to solve that; But I will search if I found good I will tell you;